# Python + Maya - How to change a float into a time value

Tags: python, maya

So I'm basically trying to create a `textField` in which users type in a `startFrame` and `endFrame` and it scales it by the value in the slider.

[image]

So, I have this, for the `floatFields`.

```
cmds.text( label='Start Frame' ) 
startFrame = cmds.floatField()

cmds.text( label='End Frame' ) 
endFrame = cmds.floatField()
```

So, from what I understand, `startFrame` and `endFrame` are floats but I'm getting this error...

> Error: TypeError: Invalid arguments for flag 'time'.  Expected (time,
>   [time]), got ( unicode, unicode )

Why are they unicode? How do I change them to time variables? I looked around, but I'm new to Maya+Python and I'm a bit confused.

Thanks.

EDIT: Here's the full code snippet.

```
def scaleAnimation():
    cmds.scaleKey( time=(startFrame,endFrame), timeScale=keyFrameScale, timePivot=0 )

cmds.frameLayout(collapsable=True, label = "Scale Keyframes", width = 475)

#get scale for the keyframes
keyFrameScale =  cmds.floatSliderGrp(label='Keyframe Scale',field=True,minValue=0.0,maxValue=2.0,value=0.5)

cmds.text( label='Start Frame' )
startFrame = cmds.floatField()

cmds.text( label='End Frame' )
endFrame =  cmds.floatField()

cmds.button(label='Scale Keyframes',command='scaleAnimation()')

cmds.setParent("..")
```

Comment: Where's the code that generates the error? You've provided the creation code for the controls, but not the code that handles the values. If you just run the four lines that you provided, there is no error.

Comment: Could you explain more in details what you are trying to achieve (ie: what the user will do in this form an how it will act)? And as said in the previous comment, please provide the code that generates the error.

Comment: `def scaleAnimation():
    cmds.scaleKey( time=(startFrame,endFrame), timeScale=keyFrameScale, timePivot=0 )`,

Basically trying to get the user to choose a time range and scale the keyframes by an amount decided by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the way you have named your variables and from the error you are getting, I suspect that you are not accessing your controls' values in the right way.

`startFrame` and `endFrame` are NOT floats. They are just the controls' names. If you use these in a function that expects `time` (as float), you will get an error, because you passed these variables which are just names as string   (Unicode) instead of passing the controls' values.

In Maya, when you create a control, the command/function that creates it returns the NAME of the created control. Egs. `u'floatField1'`

In order to access any values or other aspects of controls in Maya, you would use the control creating method itself and pass the name of the control you want to query, pass the query flag `query=True` and then pass the parameter you want to query like `value=True` or `text=True`.

In your case, the way you would do it is:

```
# First make the controls. Note the clearer variable names

cmds.text( label='Start Frame' )
startFrame_control = cmds.floatField()
cmds.text( label='End Frame' )
endFrame_control = cmds.floatField()

# this is how you should access the values

startFrame = cmds.floatField(startFrame_control, query=True, value=True)
endFrame = cmds.floatField(endFrame_control, query=True, value=True)

# NOW these are float values as you would expect.

# You could use them as time parameters in any function that expects time params.

print "The start frame is:",  startFrame
print "The end frame is:",  endFrame

cmds.scaleKey( time=(startFrame,endFrame), timeScale=keyFrameScale, timePivot=0)
```

Be sure to check out the docs: http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/floatField.html

Comment: Accepted! I need a bit more reputation before I can vote you up though. Sorry :<